# Installed gcc using xcode , but gcc still not found

Tags: xcode, gcc, osx-mavericks, oh-my-zsh

OS X 10.9.5, XCode Version 6.2.. I installed command line tools using `xcode-select --install`.

`xcode-select -p` gives `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

I was able to find gcc in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`

```
 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel        3 Apr  7 10:13 g++ -> gcc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   103188 Apr  7 10:13 gatherheaderdoc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    18608 Apr  7 10:13 gcc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1596960 Apr  7 10:13 git
```

Inspite of all this, `gcc -v` says `zsh: command not found: gcc`.

Do anyone know how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought Xcode does no longer ship GCC, it only ships Clang and GCC is a link to Clang. I might be wrong. In either case, GCC is stuck with version 4.2 due to the change to GPL 3. GCC 4.2 is kind of useless to compile today's software.

Comment: Oh! my gems are failing cos it demands gcc 4.4 or higher. whats the best way to install gcc if not xcode?

Comment: Some use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) (I do), some use [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/).